# How to send response using callback in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

Once i have params from client i want to match that string from the file system and send matching data back to client so trying to get familiar with callbacks, so in below code when i call callback it send me response with correct data but its throwing error right after that i have pasted in code.

app.js

```
app.get('/serverSearch', function (req, res) {
    var searchTxt = req.query.searchTxt;
    dirDirectory.readDirectory(function(logFiles){
        // res.json(logFiles);
        if(logFiles){
            searchFileService.readFile(searchTxt,logFiles,function(lines,err){
                        console.log('Logs',lines);
                          if (err)
                           return res.send();
                           res.json(lines);
                    })

        }
    });

    console.log('Search text', searchTxt);
});
```

service.js

```
function readFile(str,logFiles,callback){
    searchStr = str;
    for(var i=0; i<logFiles.length; i++){
        if(logFiles[i].filename !== '.gitignore'){
            fs.readFile('logs/dit/' + logFiles[i].filename, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
              if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
              }
              inspectFile(data,callback);
              callback(result);
              result = [];
            });
        }
    }

}

function inspectFile(data,callback) {
    var lines = data.split('\n');              // get the lines
    lines.forEach(function(line) {             // for each line in lines
        if(line.indexOf(searchStr) != -1) {    // if the line contain the searchSt
            result.push(line);
            // then log it
            return line;
        }
    });
    cb(callback);
}

function cb (callback) {
    callback(result);
}
```

Error

```
_http_outgoing.js:344
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
    ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

Comment: why do you even have this function cb (callback) {
    callback(result);
} result is null here. Instead directly you could have put callback(result) in the calling function

Comment: Yes i tried that approach but i was getting same error.

Comment: anyway result is null in that function, so revert back to the previous approach first.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because callback of `searchFileService.readFile` called multiple times. `fs.readFile` are called in a loop, and for each step of loop you have new callback call. Then `res.json(lines);` also called multiple times, and this is reason of error.

You should use something like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) to execute multiple async `fs.readFile` and collect their results into one callback call.

Comment: Can you please provide example of `async` with above code

Comment: @hussain just look at [example of map function](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map) in documentation. It is exactly what you're looking for.